# does something like followin exists? ('''select * from TABLE where ? in FIELD''',(VAR))

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, select, sql-like, instr

does something like followin exist?

```
('''select * from TABLE where ? in FIELD''',(VAR))
```

I need to select all table rows where FIELD just contains the text of VAR (so not needed FIELD=VAR)
I'm using python3 and sqlite3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`INSTR()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr):

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE INSTR(FIELD, ?)"
```

or the operator [`LIKE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_and_match_operators):

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE FIELD LIKE '%' || ? || '%'"
```

to get the rows that contain the value of `VAR`:

```
execute(sql, (VAR,))
```